# Pronunciation of Brötchen

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

In my family, we never pronounced *Brötchen* with a long `ö`, but rather a sound reminiscent of a diphthong `oi` or `öi`. In any case, *Brötchen* with a long `ö` sounds totally alien and unfamiliar to me.

But what is the standard German pronunciation? Is there any dialectal area (Rhineland?) where such a pronunciation is common?

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary normally includes non-standard but common pronunciations, but in [this case](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Br%C3%B6tchen) they only listed one possible pronunciation. It's also the only one I've heard. The standard way being `[ˈbʀøːtçən]`.

I tried checking forvo for a recording from a person from Rhineland without success, but it's worth noting people from different regions all pronounced it [pretty much the same way](http://www.forvo.com/word/br%C3%B6tchen/#de).

Answer (score 2):

According to Duden Volume 6 – *Aussprachewörterbuch*, the standard pronunciation of *Brötchen* is [ˈbrøːtçən].

A sound sample can be found [here](http://www.duden.de/_media_/audio/ID4110531_336792255.mp3).

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard /'bröitchen/. The normal vowel is a long or half-long ö. Maybe there is a pronunciation with öi, perhaps in Siebenbürgen or Jiddisch or perhaps with the Amish in USA.